# php gallery file i/o or database i/o? the displaying of large image volume on website.

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I've been on a project for the past few days and hit a problem displaying large quantities of images (+20gb total ~1-2gb/directory)in a gallery on one area of the site. The site is built on the bootstrap framework. I've been trying to make massive carousels that ultimately do not function fluidly due to combined /images size.

Question A: In this situation do I need i/o from a database and store images there-- is this faster than in /images folder on front end?

And b) in my php script i need to -set directories to variables/ iterate through and display images into < li >, but how do I go about putting controls on the memory usage so as to not overload browser? Any additions, suggestions, or alternatives would be greatly appreciated. Im looking for most direct means to end here.

Comment: a) Don't put images into a database to improve performance. b) it's totally up to your carousel how it handles images. You may be best off finding one that loads new images smartly on demand

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is a little generic, here are some thoughts in regards to your two questions:

**A)** No, performance pulling images from a database would most likely be worse than pulling straight from the file system. In general, it is not a good idea to store images or other binary data in databases unless you absolutely have to, because databases can't do much with this information and you are just adding an extra layer on top of the file system that doesn't need to be there. You would, however, want to store *paths* to images in your database, potentially along with other characteristics such as image dimensions, thumbnail paths, keywords, etc. Then your application would read the entries for the images to return the correct paths to the images.

**B)** You will almost certainly want to implement some sort of paging if you are displaying many hundreds or thousands of photos. If the final display must be a carousel, you will want to investigate the Javascript that drives it to determine how you could hook in a function that retrieves more results from your PHP application via an AJAX call when it reaches the end or near end of the current listing of images. If you are having problems with the browser crashing due to too many images, you will also want to remove images from the first part of the list of `<li>`s when you load new ones so that it keeps the DOM under control.

Answer (score 0):

**A)** It's a bad idea to store that much binary data into a database, even if the DB allows it, you shouldn't use it, it'll also give you much more memory consumption, all your data will be stored in the database's memory space, then copied into PHP's memory space for you to handle, which eats up twice the memory, plus the overhead of running a database server, and querying, etc.. so no, it's slower to use a database, accessing the filesystem directly is faster, if you also use varnish or other front-end caching system, you'll even be able to serve content much faster too.

What I would do is store files on the filesystem, and the best server to handle static serving like that is either G-WAN or NGINX [Source](http://nbonvin.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/apache-vs-nginx-vs-varnish-vs-gwan/), but do your read up and decide for yourself what suits you best. point is, stay away from apache, and probably host all those static files onto a separate server running a lightweight http server

**ProTip:** Save multiple copies of the same image with scaled down sizes for example 50% and another version with 25% of the original image size, this way you'll be able to send the thumbnails first for quick browsing, then when a user decides to view an image you serve up the 50% or 100% size, depending on their screen size, this way you save yourself bandwidth and memory. you also save a big 3G bill for mobile users.

**B)** This is where it makes some sense to use a database, you can index all the directories into a database, and use that to store the location of the image in the FS, and perhaps some tags, and maybe even number of views, etc...

and in the forntend you'll implement a scipt that'll fetch for example 50 thumbnails per page then the user can scroll around using some fancy JQuery, and when you need to fetch more, simply get a new result set with 50 more thumbs, etc..

this way you'll save yourself memory, bandwidth and even the users will thank you for such a lightweight browsing experience !

**Another tip:**
If you want to be able to handle bigger traffic, you might want to consider using a CDN, there are many CDN services that aren't as expensive as Amazon S3, a simple search will give you tons of resources !

Happy hacking !